# How do I know what cwl to enable for each command?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

TexStudio marks some of my commands like `\thepage` or `\yyyymmdddate` as unrecognized. I know I need to enable the relevant `.cwl` to fix this, but how am I supposed to find out which `.cwl` I want for any given command?

Or should I just enable all of the `.cwl`'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you won't need to manually activate any cwl. For quite a time now, cwls are implicitly loaded based on the `\usepackage` directives. For details see [FAQ: When are cwl files loaded?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#when-are-cwl-files-loaded).

If you document compiles, but TXS marks some commands as unrecognized, probably the cwl file is incomplete. This may be the case, in particular for the autogenerated ones. [FAQ: Where do cwl files come from](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-do-cwls-come-from)?

I just checked that neither `\thepage` nor `\yyyymmdddate` are contained in any predefined cwl. You have to find out yourself which package they come from and update the corresponding cwl files. We encourage to report improved cwls back to the TeXstudio project. That way we can provide them to all users in future versions.

*Edit*: `\thepage` the page counter. I've just added these counter accessors to the internal latex-document.cwl. Will be included in the next release.

Comment: This is informative, but doesn't explain how I can check myself whether a given command is in the cwls (and which one). You do say "I just checked that neither..." - can you please explain a bit more how you checked? Did you just search through all the cwls? (where are they?) Is there a logic to which command is supposed to be in which cwl, in case I want to contribute my own definitions?

Comment: Just read on in the FAQ: [Where are cwl files stored?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-cwl-files-stored). Basically, cwls correspond to packages (graphicx.cwl contains the commands of the package graphicx). There are some additional cwls for basic commands, namely tex.cwl and latex-*.cwl.